# Play recorded audio chunks as you receive them with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, web-audio-api

Is there a way to play the audio I am recording while I'm still recording it?

This is my code. I'm recording the audio and everytime an audio chunk is ready a call to `onaudioprocess` is made. It receives an instance of `AudioProcessingEvent`. I'm not familiar with the Web Audio API, so I'm not sure what to do to listen to it. I want my speakers to output the sound.

```
function startRecording(stream){
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var audio_input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var buffer_size = 2048;

    var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(buffer_size, 1, 1);

    recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
        // var data = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        // AudioStream.write(data);

        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = e.inputBuffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);

        console.log(e.inputBuffer)

    };

    audio_input.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
}
```

The code inside `onaudioprocess` does not work. There is no error in the console, but nothing happens.

The output of `e.inputBuffer` looks fine:

*AudioBuffer {length: 4096, duration: 0.09287981859410431, sampleRate: 44100, numberOfChannels: 1}*

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the audio processing event at
https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioprocessingevent to
see what the onprocess event does.  You basically need to copy the
events inputBuffer to the outputBuffer and you'll be able to hear the
audio.